# problem with display on Monitor

Tags: display

I get the following message at start :

```
could not apply the stored configuration for monitor.
Error on line 1 : Document must begin with an element (eg.  <book> ).
```

I am a new starter on Linux. My computer is a 4" by 4" GIGABYTE micro and came with UBUNTU (version 14) pre-installed.

I have been using it without any problem for almost 2 years. This problem started 3 days back:

The left side and the top of the display are not visible, so I have to pull out the mains plug to switch it off.

Thanks.
P.Nath.

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal you should be in your home directory `{~}:$` .. type

```
cd .config
cp monitors.xml monitors.xml.bak
rm monitors.xml
reboot
```

See if that solves the issue 
If not or it creates more of an issue .. you can go back to terminal and type

```
cd .config
cp monitors.xml.bak monitors.xml
reboot
```

that should put the original file back

if this doesn't work .. if you could try to save the monitors.xml  to a flash drive or something and open it somewhere else and edit your question copy and paste the contents into it so we can see and try to find a different solution.

lol I suggest saving it somewhere else because I have no idea how you use a 4x4 screen basically if you can open the monitors.xml and copy and paste the text in your question using that device then you can do that.